# How do Microsoft hotfixes actually work?

Tags: windows, updates, software-update

I don't get how Microsoft hotfixes work in practice. Hypothetical example:

Imagine a simple app – just one file, **CoolApp.exe**. **Hotfix1** is released to resolve an issue. Later on, **Hotfix2** is released to resolve a different issue.

Does **Hotfix2** implicitly include **Hotfix1**?

If no, then how can we enjoy the benefit of both hotfixes simultaneously?

If yes, then what happens if we need the fix that **Hotfix2** provides but we *do not* want the fix that **Hotfix1** provides?

Comment: Before answering, I should of asked, what do you mean by "hotfix"?  Do you mean updates provided by Windows Update (WU)/Microsoft Update (MU)?  "Hotfix" is actually a term Microsoft no longer uses, but is basically now LDR channel updates, which are not provided through WU/MU.

Comment: I mean hotfixes like the following: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2553116

Comment: If this is the issue you're actually faced with, have you tried updating to SP2 instead?

Comment: It *might* be the issue I'm facing. Symptoms are bang on. But I'm already on SP2 + all subsequent updates. I was going to install this hotfix but now I know better - chances are the hotfix fix is already part of either SP2 or post-SP2 updates (so long as SP2 or post-SP2 updates actually updated the same files that this hotfix targets). I guess I just need to look at all the KB articles and figure out supersedence for myself. Fun...

Comment: It's good that you started with that.  The hotfix says it only applies to SP1, but try it and see.  It can be uninstalled.  Create a Windows restore point if you're really worried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer in simple terms, **yes**.  If an update changes the version of a specific file, the fixes in Microsoft's previous versions of that file are also there.  This is why updates often supersede other updates, rather than add to the total amount of updates available.

While you can choose to apply only certain updates (assuming no dependencies), you can't choose only certain fixes be applied to a particular file.

In reality, there is much more to Windows Update than just downloading files and replacing them with newer versions.  For example, [Binary Delta Compression](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1562) downloads only the data containing the differences between files.  This technology has been used by Microsoft for nearly 10 years.

Comment: What you say makes sense. But that raises a big issue for me: if Hotfix1 causes instability, but you really need Hotfix2, you're screwed - assuming both hotfixes relate to CoolApp.exe. Most folks wouldn't know this, they'd install Hotfix2 not realising that they implicitly bought into Hotfix1's changes too.

Comment: You can _usually_ expect at least some part of Hotfix2 to correct the instability problems caused by Hotfix1

Comment: @misha256 It's a unique situation.  Only a tiny fraction of computers have a hotfix/QFE/LDR update on them.  It's even more rare to have an additional one for the same component.

Comment: It's all starting to make sense. Based on the way MS presents updates and hotfixes to us, I naively thought you could cherry-pick what you like. In reality it doesn't work that way. As per my example, CoolApp.exe can only ever be of a certain revision. Each hotfix or update upps the file to a later revision. It's only logical then that the latest revision implicitly includes all fixes of the previous revisions. Do correct me if I'm mistaken :-)

Answer (score 0):

It is a simple matter of dependency. As in your example, if Hotfix2 is an incremental update to Hotfix1, then there is no way you can install Hotfix2 alone. Whereas, if they both are totally different components altogether and doesn't have anything in common then what you are asking is a possibility (that too only if the developer has allowed it to be installed so).